# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (Id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'err.response.data')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, expo

I have a **React Native** application that I cloned. It connects with **MongoDB** using **Node.js API**. However, after registering into the app it cannot insert nor fetch the data from **MongoDB**. Also, on my simulator, I got a yellow error at the bottom of the screen which says:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'err.response.data')

Here is my code:

```
export const loginuser = userData => dispatch => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/users/login", userData)
      .then(res => {

        // save user token to local storage 
        const { token } = res.data;

        AsyncStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        console.log(AsyncStorage.setItem())

        // set token to auth header i.e authorization 
        setAuthToken(token);

        // decode the token and saveuser to deoded

        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        console.log(token)
        //set current user 

        console.log(decoded)
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

        Actions.main()
      })
      .catch(err => dispatch({
        type:GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
      )
  }
```

May i know the best solution to solve this error.
Hope for your help. Thank you

Comment: `error.response` is probably undefined and you're trying to get data from it as if it was an object.

Comment: Are you using any `Middleware`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 for the middleware i use express and body-parser

Comment: Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Comment: @Meyon have you solved it, any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please check with Axios document on how to handle errors:
https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

`err.response` might be empty:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/users/login", userData)
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```